# nil/optional or without...what is the main diff?

Tags: swift, string, function, null

what is the big difference in these two codes? I am a beginner in swift/coding at all :) thx for help

```
func hellou(_ name: String = "World") -> String {
return "Hello \(name)!"}


func hello(_ name: String? = nil) -> String {
return "Hello, \(name ?? "World")!)}
```

Comment: The main difference is that the first method won't accept nil values. try `hellou(nil)` or `hellou(yourTextField.text)`

Comment: ... i.e., the second pattern accepts optional values for the parameter, which can simplify your code in certain cases, namely when dealing with optionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some simple Playground code that demonstrates the differences:

```
import UIKit

func hellou(_ name: String = "World") -> String {
    return "Hello \(name)!"}


func hello(_ name: String? = nil) -> String {
    return "Hello, \(name ?? "World")!"
}


var someNonNilOptional:String? = "this is not nil, but it could be"
var someNilOptional:String?  // this is nil
var someNonNilString:String = "This string cannot be nil"


// First, all inputs work in the optional method
hello(someNilOptional) // this is fine because hello takes optionals
hello(someNonNilOptional) // this is also fine, because hello takes optionals
hello(someNonNilString) // this too is fine, because a string will work for an Optional(String)


// for the non-optional method, things get more dicey
hellou(someNonNilString) // this is fine, because the parameter is String not String?
hellou(someNonNilOptional!) // this works because we force-unwrap and it wasn't nil

hellou(someNilOptional!) // Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

hellou(someNonNilOptional) // compile time error
hellou(someNilOptional) // compile time error
```

There are times when you don't want an optional parameter.  The two compile-time errors above are good examples where I expect the string to have a value as a programmer, and the compiler makes sure they are.